# AngularJS: orderBy filter to reverse the order of the table rows does not work

Tags: angularjs, datatable, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table, angularjs-orderby

I am writing a web app that allows users to post to a server and the front end displays all the posts. However, when a user adds a post, it goes to the bottom of all posts first. I want the newest post to go to the top of all posts instead.

I tried using:

```
ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-'"
```

and

```
ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-index'"
```

This is my code for the table:

```
         <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-'">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>{{$index}}</td>

                  <td>{{post.username}}</td>

                  <td>{{post.title}}</td>

                  <td>{{post.content}}</td>

                  <td>{{post.comment}}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
          </div>
```

However these two approaches do not work. Is there another way?

Comment: You have to order by a property on the object. `<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-username'">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order them according to their position in the unsorted `posts` array. You can do this with a function like so:

```
$scope.newestFirst = function(post) {
    return -$scope.posts.indexOf(post);
}
```

And then in the HTML: `<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:newestFirst">`

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nLmuakj/3/). With the `newestFirst` sort, new posts get added to the top of the list.

You'll notice that even as you change the order of the posts, the index column stays the same. It seems that `$index` gives the index of each post in its *current* sort. Ordering by `$index` still appears to sort the posts by their index in the source array, but ordering by a string of gibberish produces the same result, so I think this is coincidental.

Comment: This is great but the index number changes in your fiddle. I'm looking for something where the index number stays with the post. Like the lower index numbers would be at the bottom of the page @asterism

Comment: I don't think this is possible using `$index` for the reasons mentioned above, but you can just as easily replace it with a function returning the original index of that post, such as the `oldestFirst` function in the fiddle. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nLmuakj/1/); [fiddle with clearer function names for this use case](http://jsfiddle.net/4nLmuakj/2/). @axc

Comment: This is great but question: why would it sort into a weird order when usernames are all the same or contents are all the same? It also sorts into a weird (seems random) order when there are nothing in that field (blank)? @asterism

Comment: Not sure, I haven't been able to reproduce this. From what I can tell, it seems to use the original index as the secondary sort when values are the same, and consider undefined values "bigger" than strings or integers and list them last. @axc

Comment: To reproduce the bug I was talking about, leave one of the fields completely empty/blank for all entries, and then sort by that field @asterism

Comment: Yeah, I tried that — [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/4nLmuakj/4/) with five posts with nothing in the comment field, and when I sort by comment it always goes back to being sorted by the original index, ascending. Do you have a functional example where it does otherwise?

Comment: Before that can you explain why this button dropdown does not work with the two sorting methods? I was basically trying to implement your fiddle! @asterism http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373621/bootstrap-split-button-not-working